# My UserControl isn't being rendered when used inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I have a UserControl defined in MyUserControl.xaml. If I reference this directly from another control, then it displays correctly. For example:

```
<Grid>
    <MyUserControl/>
<Grid>
```

works as expected. But if I try to use the UserControl in a DataTemplate it doesn't work. For example, if I have a DataTemplate like

```
<DataTemplate>
   <MyUserControl/>
<DataTemplate>
```

nothing gets rendered.

What's up?

Comment: We need more than that... perhaps you have no items in your collection... perhaps you didn't specify the correct `DataType` in your `DataTemplate`? Many things could have gone wrong, but we can't say because you haven't shown us your code. Please provide a [*complete, but concise, working code example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Sheridan: as you can see from my answer, this was intended as a Q&A question, rather than a fix-my-code question

Comment: Hah! I completely missed the fact that you answered your own question. However, I can't reproduce your 'problem' at all... how do you display a XAML only `UserControl`? I can just see an empty `Window` when I tried in my test project in VS2010/Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Does your UserControl have a corresponding .xaml.cs file? This seems to happen when it doesn't.

If you're using Visual Studio, try copying all the XAML from your UserControl, then deleting it from your project, adding a new UserControl (with the same name as before), then pasting your content back into the XAML file. This will ensure that you have the correct .xaml.cs file set up.

Comment: You'll definitely get a +1 from me if this turns out to be the correct answer... that would be an excellent catch if so.